# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: i/o timeout error in GKE pod

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

While running kubectl get pods command in GKE pod, we are getting the following error frequently. Some times, when started 2 pods(deployment) on 2 nodes, on one pod, the command executes successfully and on another pod, the command gives the following error on the another pod on the same docker image:

- Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: i/o timeout

We are getting the following error while running pods(chaos-mesh master controller:chaos-controller-manager-d945b5d5b-f2pr7) in GKE as well, looks similar to above:

- "error": "Get "https://10.0.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: i/o timeout"}
- Failed to get API Group-Resources       {"error": "Get "https://10.0.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.0.1:443: i/o timeout"}

Can any one suggest any solution to it. As you know google doesn't provide any support for pay as you go. This puts us in very difficult situation, even we pay, but we don;t get support.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share any additional information about your deployments?

Answer (score 1):

tldr; please check the firewall rules, CNI configuration and network policies on your GKE cluster.

It seems like `10.0.0.1:443` is the endpoint for "kubernetes" Service, the Service for in-cluster pods to access the kube-apiserver. The problem is some Pods could NOT access this endpoint, most likely the misconfiguration Pod Networking. Please make sure CNI is working well and kube-proxy create the correct iptables or lvs rules

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the Control plane in GKE was restricted to only authorized networks and my VM's external IP address wasn't in there, after adding my ip to the authorized networks list it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to allow 443 in the security groups to make it work.